# Flaw when merging questions

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, merged-question

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32671/basic-audio-amplifer-circuit-with-transistors) was merged with [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25748/simple-audio-amplifier-using-transistors/32672#32672).

My answer to the first was the asker's accepted. But after the merge the accept has been undone; most likely because it's another person's question.

[image]

An accepted answer tops the list of answers as a hint to other users that it may be relevant. Now that it's no longer the accepted one it may move all down the list.

I don't like the way this works, but I have no immediate solution. The question the other one was merged with could also have had an accepted answer. Maybe questions shouldn't be merged if they have both an accepted answer?

Comment: If they are the same question they should be merged. They were asking for the same thing, I did miss the "book request" which was an invalid part of the answer. I removed it and I removed the 4 posts that were just a link.

Comment: Yes, but I want my money,back, don't you understand! ;-) I didn't realize the deleted answers at first (you know that as a 10k+ I still see the number of 6 at the top). I agree with the deletion, I pointed out to Leon that none of the 5 original answers had a schematic.

Comment: accept votes don't count towards the reputation cap for the day, is that what issue you were having?

Comment: @Kortuk - No, I know that, that's why I got 305 in rep the day before: because of 7 accept votes (a personal record). It's that the answer doesn't show as the accepted anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It was a very low quality question which as the close showed was duplicated on the site. If the quality of the question seems low attempt to improve question quality or close before writing answers.

In this case you lost an accepted vote immediately because of a merge operation. I performed the merge operation because there was a very high quality answer that needed to be saved but that the question was a duplicate. If I had left it there when we did our cleanup of old inactive closed questions you would have lost the vote. This would have been in 4-6 months and would have lost the accepts at that point.

You would have broken your record by then also, we have had constant and steady increase of users visiting our site. Maybe that would have made it less of an issue.